# Upload with paperclip, sinatra and mongoid

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid, paperclip

I have a problem using the paperclip with sinatra and mongoid.
When I upload displays the following error:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError - No handler found for {"tempfile"=>#, "filename"=>"image-[Converted].jpg", "content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "size"=>35222}:
```

In the model so I left:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar,
    :path           => ':attachment/:id/:style.:extension',
    :default_url => '/images/missing_portrait_:style.jpg',
    :styles => {
      :original => '1920x1680>',
      :small    => '100x100#',
      :medium   => '250x250',
      :large    => '500x500>'
    }
end
```

And the route / upload is as follows:

```
post '/upload' do
  User.create! ::avatar => to_paperclip(params[:file])
end

def to_paperclip(image)
  paperclip = {}
  paperclip['tempfile'] = image[:tempfile]
  paperclip['filename'] = image[:filename]
  paperclip['content_type'] = image[:type]
  paperclip['size'] = image[:tempfile].size
  paperclip  
end
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not find any solution with the paperclip,but I ended up using the carrierwave and it worked what I needed

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
user = User.new()
user.avatar  = params[:avatar][:tempfile]
user.avatar_file_name = params[:avatar][:filename]
```